# CDN Verizon Premium - where is the Staging URL

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Where can I locate the staging url for my Azure Verizon Premium CDN

Currently I'm using Azure storage & then using Azure Verizon Premium CDN infront of it to handle all the traffic.

The issue I have is the site is live now & making changes to the rules is not without issue on a live site. I'm trying to find where the staging url lives.

According to the documentation: https://docs.edgecast.com/cdn/index.html#HRE/Environment.htm#Staging
referenced from Azure docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference

> Requests may be directed to the Staging environment by prepending "staging." to the hostname defined in a CDN URL.
> Sample CDN URL (Production):
> http://wpc.0001.edgecastcdn.net/800001/myorigin/marketing/brochure.pdf
> Sample CDN URL (Staging):
> http://**staging**.wpc.0001.edgecastcdn.net/800001/myorigin/marketing/brochure.pdf

Applying to a sample file on my domain would be (Production, Staging): http://wpc.0001.edgecastcdn.net/8011BE84/atsworkspacewebapp/atsworkspacewebapp/index.html [http://**staging**.wpc.0001.edgecastcdn.net/8011BE84/atsworkspacewebapp/atsworkspacewebapp/index.html](http://staging.wpc.0001.edgecastcdn.net/8011BE84/atsworkspacewebapp/atsworkspacewebapp/index.html)

Through the Postman app I can get to Production (must disable SSL verification), but not Staging. That domain is void.

Where would I find the staging url?

Comment: From DNS service provider, create a CNAME record that points the your origin url. http://staging.{domain}.com/something

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution here @Ryan ?